# DRF download file from FileField

Tags: django-rest-framework

I used DRF REST to achieve file upload function.

models.py

```py
class NetworkConfig(models.Model):
    ipaddress = models.GenericIPAddressField(verbose_name='Device IP')
    configfile = models.FileField(max_length=300,upload_to='networkconfig/')
    create_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'NetworkConfig'
        verbose_name_plural = verbose_name
        db_table = 'NetworkConfig'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ipaddress
```

serializers.py

```py
class NetworkConfigSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    create_time = serializers.DateTimeField(read_only=True, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

    class Meta:
        model = NetworkConfig
        fields = '__all__'
```

settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/tmp/'
```

views.py

```py
class NetworkFilesViewSet(ViewSet):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser)

    def upload(self,request):
        file_serializer = NetworkConfigSerializer(data=request.data)
        if file_serializer.is_valid():
            file_serializer.save()
            return Response(file_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(file_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

urls.py

```
path(r'api/networkconfig', views.NetworkFilesViewSet.as_view({'post': 'upload'})),
```

When I used postman to upload a file ,MySQL table looks like:

```
id | ipaddress  | configfile             | create_time                
 1 | 10.12.2.19 | networkconfig/test.txt | 2020-09-09 19:17:58.723851
```

and the file store in /tmp/networkconfig/.

Now how can i download this file use REST from FileField?

Comment: just add another `view`, which will do get request and into `serializer` add `configfile` in `fields`

Comment: @BakhtiyarBekbergen Can you explain it in more detail

Comment: just return instance after create operation with all fields that's all